# I have tried many names for Pokemon Go but they say it's not available

Tags: pokemon-go

I need a nick name for Pokemon Go to continue the game. I tried more than 100 names . Can you please send me a available name.

Comment: Have you tried `Devanshi` or `Devanshi13082016`?

Comment: it's because the name isn't available. Try adding numbers or using less common word/ combination of words.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the possiblity that, that name has been taken, this might be a bug.
**Restart the game, and try again.** Already tested this.